# How to display records from one table where condition is from another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I currently have two table user and user_likes, from this table I want to display all the records from user where the condition is from user_likes table.

For eg. I am jack and my interest is female between the age 20 to 35 and base on this information I want to disply the record who is female between the age 20 to 35.

Heres my table (user):

```
username(pk)   first_name   last_name   email              date_of_birth(date)    gender
john123        john         mask        john@gmail.com      1984-12-31            Male
jack123        jack         cunning     jack@gmail.com      1999-01-23            Female
pink123        pink         pop         pink@gmail.com      2000-05-01            Female
```

And Heres my other table (user_likes):

```
username(fk)   gender_likes       age_from    to_age
john123         Female              18         30     
jack123         Female              20         35
pink123         Male                25         35
```

I try this problem using join but I couldn't figure out how to display the exact records I want (eg between 20 to 45):

```
select * from user inner join user_likes on user_likes.age_from <= DATEDIFF(year, user.date_of_birth, GETDATE()) AND user_likes.to_age >= DATEDIFF(year, user.date_of_birth, GETDATE())
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: based on this table it should show the user pink information as pink is between the age 20-45.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a query that will fetch all users that matches john123’s criteria:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM 
    user_likes l
    INNER JOIN users u
        ON FLOOR(DATEDIFF (NOW(), u.date_of_birth)/365) BETWEEN l.age_from AND l.to_age
        AND u.gender = l.gender_likes
        AND l.username <> u.username
WHERE l.username = 'john123'
```

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iz4XzjCiJwRgHkFBvUBSUY/1)** with your sample data returns:

```
| username | first_name | last_name | email          | date_of_birth | gender |
| -------- | ---------- | --------- | -------------- | ------------- | ------ |
| jack123  | jack       | cunning   | jack@gmail.com | 1999-01-23    | Female |
| pink123  | pink       | pop       | pink@gmail.com | 2000-05-01    | Female |
```

Comment: I get this error    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' GETDATE ( ) BETWEEN l . age_from AND l . age_to  AND u . gender = l . gender  W' at line 1

Comment: idk why it said l.gender W'(I gave it as l.gender WHERE like you commented)

Comment: @SangTonsing: I updated my answer, would you please give it another try?

Comment: the query actually works(no error message) but the records is not displayed(not any records)

Comment: @SangTonsing: this seems to work fine with your sample data. I added a link to a fiddle in my answer so you can check and possibly play around with the solution.

Comment: okay, maybe theres something wrong from my side as the data that I provided are just a sample, I'll work on that and thanks for the help...

Comment: @SangTonsing . . . I don't think approximations on the age calculation are a good idea.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, why is that?? Is there any better way??

Comment: @GMB, why did I get that error #1604 that I mentioned in the above comment but works on the database on the link that your provided? This will actually help me solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

JOIN operation supports filter in their ON clause, so you'd have to check the date difference between the current date and the users `date_of_birth` against the `from` and `to` values of the `user_like` table:

```
SELECT [...]
INNER JOIN user_likes 
ON user_likes.age_from <= DATEDIFF(year, user.date_of_birth, GETDATE())
   AND user_likes.age_to >= DATEDIFF(year, user.date_of_birth, GETDATE())
```

Comment: I have updated the query above like you commented but it gives an error. Can you check the query above which I used. I have updated it.

Comment: @SangTonsing what error? Please be more specific when asking questions and reporting problems. Take a tour to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to see how to properly ask questions here on StackOverflow.

Comment: sorry about that... this is the error I got from the server-----#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' GETDATE ( ) )  AND user_likes . age_to >= DATEDIFF( year , user . date_of_birth' at line 1 ------ the query is exactly like you commented @Davide Vitali

Answer (score 0):

Ages are quite tricky to deal with.  I recommend operations on the date of birth and the current date, like this:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM user_likes l JOIN
     users u
     ON u.gender = l.gender_likes AND
        l.username <> u.username AND
        u.date_of_birth >= curdate() - INTERVAL l.to_age YEAR AND
        u.date_of_birth < curdate() - INTERVAL l.from_age YEAR 
WHERE l.username = 'john123';
```

I am not sure if by `to_age` you mean for it to be inclusive or exclusive, so the logic might require adding or subtracting a year to that logic.

Comment: I don't understand why I get this error --- #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'u . date_of_birth >= curdate( ) - INTERVAL l . to_age YEAR AND u . date_of_birth' at line 1 --- from your query that you provided(I get this error from every query that I got from here), do you have any idea?